# I'm facing a problem when I go back to the Activity from its Fragment using addToBackStack(null) the Activity's button visibility gone

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making login signup Activity [**Login and Signup Activity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Aqo.png)
when i click on login button it will take me to login fragment [**Login Fragment**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Lm4.png) and when I click on signup button it will take me to signup fragment [**Signup Fragment**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyDC2.png)

when I move to any one of the Fragment from the Activity, the login and signup button of activity is also visible in the fragment for this is used
`sign_btn.visibility=View.GONE`
`login_btn.visibility=View.GONE`
inside the **setOnClickListener ** function of both buttons.

But when I go back to the Activity from one of the Fragemnt using **addToBackStack(null)**
the Activity's **login** and **signup button** visibilty is still gone how to visible the button after I move back to Activity
I am using Kotlin Langauge
**Main Activity code**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var login_btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.login)
        var sign_btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup)
        login_btn.setOnClickListener {
            sign_btn.visibility=View.GONE
            login_btn.visibility=View.GONE

            val loginfragment: Fragment = LoginFragment()
            val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, loginfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        }

        sign_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val signupfragment:Fragment=signup()
            val  fragmentTransaction=supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,signupfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
            sign_btn.visibility=View.GONE
            login_btn.visibility=View.GONE


        }

    }



}
```

**Login Fragemnt code**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup



class LoginFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)

    }

}
```

**signup Fragemnt code**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup


class signup : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach you've taken Because the main problem is that the fragments' root view doesn't have a background color or it's maybe transparent and that's why buttons are visible in fragments and you don't have to do like this.

```
sign_btn.visibility=View.GONE
login_btn.visibility=View.GONE
```

You can set a background for the root view in fragments. You'll see the buttons aren't visible.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Sir I tried this but Actvity's buttons are still visible when I move to the fragment

Comment: Ooh yeah, I can guess what happened, The activity child's view and fragment root view has been overlapped by each other, you can use a default fragment like MainFragment as well and put your buttons there.